# Superscript-like text on a text

Tags: superscripts

I want to add a small text on a regular one.
It looks like a superscript but the difference is the regular text won't have any break.
I don't know how to explain the situation correctly so I added a sample image showing what I want to do.

[image]

Any suggestions how to type this in latex?

Comment: Image link fixed. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 11):

Just for fun, with the experimental [`xcoffins` package](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/xcoffins). Special alignment tasks like this formed some of the inspiration for this new package/feature.

The two text elements are set in separate "coffins". The smaller one is then scaled down. (Since I've already used the full gamut of design type sizes available: `\tiny`-`\Huge`.)

Finally, the coffins are joined by their right top (`r,t`) poles with an (optional) offset `(0pt,-0.1em)` before being typeset.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\BigText
\NewCoffin\SmallText

\begin{document}\sffamily
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\BigText{\Huge Tex}%
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\SmallText{\tiny Superscript}%
  \ScaleCoffin\SmallText{0.75}{0.75}%
  \JoinCoffins\BigText[r,t]\SmallText[r,t](0pt,-0.1em)%
  \TypesetCoffin\BigText
\end{document}
```

[image]

The kerning was not the focus of the question, but since it has been mentioned in a comment: it is quite easy to add if desired.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\NewCoffin\BigText
\NewCoffin\SmallText

\begin{document}\sffamily
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\BigText{\Huge T\kern-0.175emex}%
  \SetHorizontalCoffin\SmallText{\tiny Superscript}%
  \ScaleCoffin\SmallText{0.65}{0.65}%
  \JoinCoffins\BigText[r,t]\SmallText[r,t](0pt,-0.15em)%
  \TypesetCoffin\BigText
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice, but too bad the kerning between "T" and "e" is lost.

Comment: @barbarabeeton what would cause the kerning to be lost? I don't think it is lost. It looks the same as David's to me.

Comment: yes, but david's looks so dreadful that i didn't even bother to comment.  look at the kerning in the original example.  it's maybe just a hair tight for my taste, but better than most others here.  the goal should be to have the same visual spacing between the "T" and the "e" as there is between the "e" and the "x"; obviously, this is somewhat subjective, but it's one of the things that differentiates a good professional font from an amateur one.  (i think knuth didn't kern cap/lowercase pairs in most cm fonts; a shame, really.  others have remarked on that too.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton ah, ok. I thought you meant that something I did broke the normal kerning of the T-e pair. Anyway, it could be easily added, but that was not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 8):

Something like that? I used the `stackengine` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\setstackgap{S}{-1.6ex}
\def\stackalignment{r}
\stackon{\color{IndianRed3}\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries T{\kern-0.15em}ex}{\sffamily\scriptsize\color{LightSteelBlue3} Superscript\kern0.6em}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** As pointed by Steven B. Segletes, you may obtain the same result with the `\stackinset` command, which has a simpler syntax in this situation:

```
\stackinset{r}{1em}{t}{0.1ex}{\sffamily\scriptsize\color{LightSteelBlue3} Superscript}{\color{IndianRed3}\fontsize{60}{0}\selectfont\sffamily\bfseries Tex}
```

It has  6 arguments: the first two are horizontal alignment and a possible horizontal offset; the next two are verticakl alignment and a vertical offset. The last two are the inset and anchor items themselves (in that order).

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it, though I am using a `\stackinset`.

Comment: @ Steven B. Segletes: Thanks for your comment. I incorporated your suggestion into my answer. I don't use your package very often, so I didn't think of this solution, which is simpler for such a job, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\Huge Tex%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-25,11.5){\tiny Superscript}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm assuming here that this is for some kind of logo setting where fine tuning the exact placement by coordinate makes sense. If you actually want the kind of running annotation as used in some linguistic applications or Japanese Ruby, then you want a different method (and there are specialist packages available)

Answer (score 4):

Can't let this go without `tikz`, so game on:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0pt]
  \node[font=\sffamily\Huge] (a) {Tex};
  \node[scale=0.4,font=\sffamily,anchor=north east,yshift=-0.3ex] at (a.north east) {Superscript};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: needs the "T" and "e" to be kerned better.  so the "Superscript" will have to be shrunk even further.

Answer (score 4):

May I contribute with a MetaPost solution? :-) It uses the tight integration of MetaPost in LuaLaTeX, directly using the document fonts and font-related specific units of TeX (`em`, `ex`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
{\sffamily
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
  draw textext("\Huge Tex"); 
  draw textext("\tiny Superscript") scaled .75 shifted (\mpdim{1.6em}, \mpdim{2.8ex});; 
endfig;         
\end{mplibcode}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution with boxes

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\makebox[4em][l]{%
  \sffamily
  \huge T%
  \makebox[-4pt][l]{\raisebox{1.3ex}{\tiny superscript}}%
  \Huge ex%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 3):

Like Bernard, I use `stackengine`, but here I use a `\stackinset`, instead of a `\stackon`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\sffamily\stackinset{r}{2ex}{t}{2pt}{Superscript}{\scalebox{7}{Tex}}
\end{document}
```

[image]